# Counter with lambda over map java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am trying to convert this:

```
Map<String,Long> parties = new HashMap<>();
parties.add("a", 1);
...
Long counter = 0l;

for (Long votes : parties.values()){
    counter += votes;
}
```

To lambda in Java8 , I try it with reduce like this :

```
parties.entrySet().stream().reduce((stringLongEntry, stringLongEntry2) -> /*Here I Stack*/)
```

But I don't know how to continue.

PS :I know I can make it with :
    `parties.values().stream().count();` but i want to find another approach.

Comment: Why do you want to find another way?

Comment: Are you always storing 1 in your values? In this case, the size of the map is all you need.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner no I don't aways put 1 , it was just an example

Comment: So why do you think that `parties.values().stream().count()` was a solution to *sum* the contained values?

Comment: `parties.add`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
counter = parties.values().stream().map((votes) -> votes).reduce(counter, (a, i) -> a+i);
```

Moreover there are few mistakes in your code:

- Using `Map<String,Long> parties = new HashMap<>();` is the correct way however your one is ot errorneous.
- `HashMap` doesn't have `.add(..)` method, but `.put(..)` method:

  ```
  parties.put("a",1L);
  ```
- Since your value is `Long`, you have to use `1L` or `1l` instead of whole `1` to specify a `Long` value.

Comment: I would prefer to write `L` rather than `l`, because the last one looks like `1`

Comment: There is not need for `map` if you're doing it this way (it does nothing more than add characters to your code)... However, I prefer using a LongStream while manipulating primitive values.

Comment: There is no sense in passing `counter` to `reduce`. The only valid value for a reduction doing summing is `0L`, hence you should provide that value directly rather than an existing variable.

Answer (score 5):

If you are always storing `1` as the value for each key, then the total count will always match the size of the map. You can get it simply with `parties.size()`.

If you store different values for each key, then counting how many values you have in the map is wrong. You should sum them instead:

```
long total = parties.values().stream().mapToLong(v -> v).sum();
```

Comment: Hello , the 1 it was just an example , it can be any Long number . And about your answer your solution is exactly as mine . Here you have the documentation of count :                                                                               
      Returns the count of elements in this stream.  This is a special case of
      a <a href="package-summary.html#Reduction">reduction</a> and is
      equivalent to:
      <pre>{@code
          return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();
      }</pre>

Comment: @RobertoFernandez It's not the same as yours. Counting to n is the same as summing 1 n times, that's what the docs say. But if you have values other than 1 in the map, then count() and sum() will return different values

Answer (score 3):

1. `parties.values().stream().mapToLong(l -> l).sum();`
2. `parties.values().stream().reduce(0L, (a, b) -> a + b);`

---

3. `parties.entrySet().stream().mapToLong(Map.Entry::getValue).sum();`
4. `parties.entrySet().stream().mapToLong(Map.Entry::getValue).reduce(0L, (a, b) -> a + b);`

---

The explanation for the question in the comments. Here we can write either `(Map.Entry<String, Long> i) ->  i.getValue()` or `i ->  i.getValue()`. But it will more readable if we replace it for a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) like `Map.Entry::getValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I am new with lambdas , what does the '::' ?

Comment: @RobertoFernandez, I added the small explanation to the answer

Comment: What’s the point of using `.entrySet().stream().mapToLong(Map.Entry::getValue)` instead of the straight-forward `.values().stream()`?

Comment: @Holger, OP wanted through `entrySet`

Comment: The question doesn’t look like the focus was on `entrySet()` (otherwise, a solution which just maps to the values afterwards was just a disguise rather than an appropriate answer). It seems more like the OP wants a reduction based solution rather than invoking an existing method like `count()` (which doesn’t work anyway)…

Answer (score 2):

if you insist on entrySet -

```
parties.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.getValue()).reduce(0L, (longValue1, longValue2) -> longValue1 + longValue2)
```